# Avoid line breaks when using out-file

Tags: powershell, line-breaks

I'm getting a little frustrated on a little PowerShell script I'm writing.

Basically I loop through text files to check every line against an array of regular expression patterns.
The result gets piped to the out-file cmdlet which appends it to another text file.

```
Get-ChildItem $logdir -Recurse -Include @('*.txt') | Get-Content | ForEach-Object { 
Select-String $patterns -InputObject $_ | Out-File $csvpath -Append -Width 1000 }
```

My problem is that I can't get out-file to omit those additional line breaks it creates in the file behind $csvpath (three after each line).
I could use .NET framework classes to achieve the same thing but I'd rather stick to pure PowerShell

Comment: `foreach { Select-String -InputObject $_ }`? Why not just pipe into `Select-String` directly?

Comment: Hi Johannes,

to be honest, I don't know how this might help.

Comment: It was no answer to your problem (hence a comment to your question and *not* an answer); just a note of how you could reduce clutter in your command there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why don't you use `Add-Content`?

```
gci $logdir -rec *.txt | gc | select-string $pattern | add-content $csvpath
```

You don't need to specify the width and `-append` switch, the file size is not doubled by default (although you can specify encoding) and it seems that there is no problem with the empty lines like you have.

Comment: Glad to help ;) It works, but generally it may be tricky to format some objects. In this case I guess `ToString()` is called on each `MatchInfo` object. For many other types `ToString()` returns just a type name (no useful info). Then it is needed as Keith suggests to specify concrete property.

Answer (score 16):

Keep in mind that Select-String outputs MatchInfo objects and not strings - as is shown by this command:

```
gci $logdir -r *.txt | gc | select-string $patterns | format-list *
```

You are asking for an implicit rendering of the MatchInfo object to string before being output to file.  For some reason I don't understand, this is causing additional blank lines to be output.  You can fix this by specifying that you only want the Line property output to the file e.g.:

```
gci $logdir -r *.txt | gc | select-string $patterns | %{$_.Line} | 
    Out-File $csvpath -append -width 1000
```