# PowerShell: Why does Out-File break long line into smaller lines?

Tags: powershell

Try this little experiment. Create a file `Foo.txt` with a very long line of text (say 500 chars long) like this:

```
// Foo.txt
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
```

Now issue the following command:

```
$ Get-Content Foo.txt | Select-String "a" | Out-File Foo2.txt
```

You will find that the long line of string has been broken down into smaller lines in `Foo2.txt`. The length of each smaller line is the same as the console width.

Why does **Out-File** break the long line into smaller line when the output is not headed to the console?

And why does Out-File not break down the lines for the following command?

```
$ Get-Content Foo.txt | Out-File Foo3.txt
```

Comment: does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675552/avoid-line-breaks-when-using-out-file ? I think there's a discussion of this general topic - output gets formatted for a certain width of monitor - in "Effective Powershell" by Keith Hill, free download.  Anyway, I don't know why, hope that link helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be explained by the fact that the result of `Get-Content Foo.txt | Select-String "a"` is of type `MatchInfo`, it's not a `string`.

just test :

```
Get-Content Foo.txt | Select-String "a" | Format-list *
```

Comment: JPBlanc: Thanks, that helped. Any idea why Out-File formats MatchInfo like it was headed to a console, but does not for String?

Comment: @Ashwin The behavior looks consistent for complex objects e.g. `MatchInfo` or `DirectoryInfo` etc... For example try this: `Get-Item C:\Windows | Out-File C:\Test.txt`. I think PowerShell needs to send complex objects to the object formatting engine first before it writes the textual representation to file.

Comment: Andy Arismendi: That explanation makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: This seemed to make sense until I look down at @Tahir Hassan answer.

Comment: @Santhos The 04/02/2012 I answered the question, Hassam gives a turn arround not an answer to the question the 25/03/2015.

Answer (score 26):

You can adjust where Out-File breaks lines using the -width parameter

```
$ Get-Content Foo.txt | Select-String "a" | Out-File -width 1000 Foo2.txt
```

Answer (score 14):

```
$ Get-Content Foo.txt | Select-String "a" | Add-Content Foo2.txt
```

Use `Add-Content` (or you could use `Set-Content` if you wish to overwrite the file).