# Why does Select-String add empty lines?

Tags: powershell

Here is a minimal repro example.

Expected result:

```
PS C:\> ("a", "b")
a
b
PS C:\> ("a", "b") | Select-String "b"
b
PS C:\>
```

Actual result:

```
PS C:\> ("a", "b")
a
b
PS C:\> ("a", "b") | Select-String "b"

b


PS C:\>
```

As you can see, the second output has one empty line before and two empty lines after the matched lines.

**Why does that happen? And what can I do about it?**

(Note: This is a minimal example. In my real code, I'm parsing `svn status` output for uncommitted files and I get the same problem of spurious newlines.)

Comment: You can pipe that out to `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line` to get rid of the newlines but I have no idea why it **adds** the newlines so I'll wait for someone else to answer...

Comment: That is pure formatting artifacts. You should not depend on particular format, but should use properties to get values you need.

Comment: @PetSerAl are you saying that `Select-String` does a implicit version of `Format-*`? :O

Comment: @Shaneis No. Default `Out-Default` have implicit version of  `Format-*`.

Comment: Interesting! Cheers @PetSerAl

Comment: @PetSerAl: Indeed, my mistake was assuming that the result is a string. Still, this is an unfortunate choice of default formatting, if Select-String wants to be an easy-to-use replacement for `findstr` and `grep`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason for weird output is that Powershell is all about objects. In this particular case, `Select-String` returns `MatchInfo` object(s). Like so,

```
PS C:\> $o = ("a", "b") | Select-String "b"
PS C:\> $o

b


PS C:\> $o.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    MatchInfo                                System.Object
```

For extra confusion, explicit call to `ToString()` doesn't output the line breaks:

```
PS C:\> $o.ToString()
b
PS C:\>
```

For a work-around, query MatchInfo's Line property like so,

```
PS C:\>  ("a", "b") | Select-String "b" | % { $_.Line }
b
PS C:\>
```

Please see also Keith Hill's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2676345) about similar a question.